# Join on same table gives too many results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

My head is spinning on the reason why I get too many results on the following query:

Based on the following 2 tables:

P4query:

```
+------------+----+-----------------+--------+----------+
| Date       | Id | MeteringPointId | Reason | StatusId |
+------------+----+-----------------+--------+----------+
| 2013-08-29 | 60 |               2 | DAY    |       60 |
| 2013-08-29 | 59 |               2 | INT    |       59 |
| 2013-08-29 | 50 |               3 | DAY    |       50 |
| 2013-08-28 | 58 |               3 | DAY    |       58 |
| 2013-08-28 | 57 |               3 | INT    |       57 |
| 2013-08-28 | 56 |               2 | DAY    |       56 |
| 2013-08-28 | 55 |               2 | INT    |       55 |
```

And
P4Reading:

```
+-------------+------+---------+----------+---------------------+------+-------------+
| EnergyMeter | Id   | QueryId | Register | Time                | Unit | Value       |
+-------------+------+---------+----------+---------------------+------+-------------+
| 15524067    | 2406 |      59 | 2.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:30:00 | WH   |       0.000 |
| 15524067    | 2609 |      59 | 1.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:30:00 | WH   | 5959289.000 |
| 15524067    | 2243 |      59 | 2.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:15:00 | WH   |       0.000 |
| 15524067    | 2448 |      59 | 1.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:15:00 | WH   | 5959179.000 |
```

I use the following query where I created a JOIN on the P4Reading table (same table) to get the values from the previous 15 minutes. This works nice but I get to many values. I looks like I am short of a join or a where statement but can't get a hold of it. I don't know where the problems is coming from.

```
SELECT `P4Query`.`MeteringPointId`, `table1`.`EnergyMeter`, `table1`.`Register`,
       `table1`.`Time`, `table1`.`Unit`, `table1`.`Value`,
      (`table2`.`Value` - `table1`.`Value`)/1000 as totaal
FROM P4Query, P4Reading table1
INNER JOIN P4Reading table2 ON `table1`.`Time` = (`table2`.`Time` - INTERVAL 15 minute)
WHERE (`P4Query`.`Id` = `table1`.`QueryId`)
ORDER BY `table1`.`Time` DESC;
```

I would expect the following:

```
+-----------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+------+-------------+---------------+
| MeteringPointId | EnergyMeter | Register | Time                | Unit | Value       | totaal        |
+-----------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+------+-------------+---------------+
|               2 | 15524067    | 1.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:30:00 | WH   | 5959289.000 |     0.1380000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 2.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:30:00 | WH   |       0.000 |     0.0000000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 1.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:15:00 | WH   | 5959179.000 |     0.1100000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 2.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:15:00 | WH   |       0.000 |     0.0000000 |
```

But I get:

```
+-----------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+------+-------------+---------------+
| MeteringPointId | EnergyMeter | Register | Time                | Unit | Value       | totaal        |
+-----------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+------+-------------+---------------+
|               2 | 15524067    | 2.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:30:00 | WH   |       0.000 |  5959.4270000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 1.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:30:00 | WH   | 5959289.000 | -5959.2890000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 1.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:30:00 | WH   | 5959289.000 |     0.1380000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 2.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:30:00 | WH   |       0.000 |     0.0000000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 1.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:15:00 | WH   | 5959179.000 |     0.1100000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 2.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:15:00 | WH   |       0.000 |  5959.2890000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 1.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:15:00 | WH   | 5959179.000 | -5959.1790000 |
|               2 | 15524067    | 2.8.0    | 2013-08-29 23:15:00 | WH   |       0.000 |     0.0000000 |
```

I have a fiddle ready: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2bdf/1

Comment: what are table1 and table2? To me it seems like you are merging 3 tables

Comment: yes, @TimBodeit is right. you've got three tables going on: `P4Query, P4Reading table1, and P4Reading table2`. When you've got two tables under the same FROM thats kind of an implicit cartesian product. Looks like this doubled your results (as compared to the expectations you mention)

Comment: please include all 3 tables, otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: I have included all tables table1 and table2 are an alias of P4Reading so I can deduct the time - 15 minutes from it.

Comment: As it was pointed out, `FROM P4Query, P4Reading table1` is a `JOIN` and since it does not seem to have have its `WHERE`, it will be (at least partially) **Cartesian**.

Comment: Mixing implicit ans explicit jopins can give bad results. Never do this. In fact never use implicit joins again as they are a SQL antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your query with table aliases so it is easier to read:

```
SELECT pq.`MeteringPointId`, pr1.`EnergyMeter`, pr1.`Register`, pr1.`Time`, pr1.`Unit`,
       pr1.`Value`, (pr2.`Value` - pr1.`Value`)/1000 as totaal
FROM P4Query pq, P4Reading pr1 INNER JOIN
     P4Reading pr2
     ON pr1.`Time` = (pr2.`Time` - INTERVAL 15 minute)
WHERE (pq.`Id` = pr1.`QueryId`)
ORDER BY pr1.`Time` DESC;
```

You are mixing join formats.  It also looks like you are missing the condition on `id` between `pr1` and `pr2`.  This may be what you want:

```
SELECT pq.`MeteringPointId`, pr1.`EnergyMeter`, pr1.`Register`, pr1.`Time`, pr1.`Unit`,
       pr1.`Value`, (pr2.`Value` - pr1.`Value`)/1000 as totaal
FROM P4Query pq join
     P4Reading pr1
     on pq.`Id` = pr1.`QueryId` join
     P4Reading pr2
     ON pq.`Id` = pr2.`QueryId` and
        pr1.`Time` = (pr2.`Time` - INTERVAL 15 minute)
ORDER BY pr1.`Time` DESC;
```

This adds the additional join condition and makes the join syntax consistent.

I am a bit suspicious of this condition on time (`pr1.Time = (pr2.Time - INTERVAL 15 minute)`).  This require absolute precision for the time value.  Under many circumstances, even regularly spaced times could be off by a few milliseconds -- causing the equality to fail.

Comment: Hey thanks but still not the result I would like to have. The Time is no issue. Only value in the Time column would be full minutes. So this will work just fine. The example you are giving has mixed up Id's with the QueryId. I fixed that but still not the result I am looking for. I have doubt whether I should use the join in combination with a where clause.

Comment: @user1745054 . . . (I fixed the join condition.)  I'm surprised that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's my lack of knowledge but we now join on pr2.`Queryid` before P4Reading pr2 is set as an alias. This doesn't work. I added the data in a sqlfiddle to see it. This is an export of the actual data. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2bdf

Comment: @user1745054 . . . The version now in the query returns exactly six rows.  Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: @Gordon... thanks for your help, I needed 1 extra join which I figured out myself. You helped me into the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The right query I used:

```
SELECT pq.`MeteringPointId`, pr1.`EnergyMeter`, pr1.`Register`, 
  pr1.`Time`, pr1.`Unit`, pr1.`Value`, 
 (pr2.`Value` - pr1.`Value`)/1000 as totaal
FROM P4Query pq 
JOIN P4Reading pr1 ON pq.`Id` = pr1.`QueryId` 
JOIN P4Reading pr2 ON pq.`Id` = pr2.`QueryId` 
   AND pr1.`Time` = (pr2.`Time` - INTERVAL 15 minute) 
   AND pr1.`Register` = pr2.`Register`
ORDER BY pr1.`Time` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query -

```
SELECT distinct `table2`.`MeteringPointId`, `table1`.`EnergyMeter`, `table1`.`Register`,
   `table1`.`Time`, `table1`.`Unit`, `table1`.`Value`,
  (`table2`.`Value` - `table1`.`Value`)/1000 as totaal
  FROM P4Query table1
INNER JOIN P4Reading table2 ON `table1`.`Time` = (`table2`.`Time` - INTERVAL 15 minute)
 WHERE (`table1`.`Id` = `table2`.`QueryId`)
ORDER BY `table1`.`Time` DESC;
```